# How to hide the log in form of a website to make sure that only the owner or admins can log in to the site?

Tags: web-applications, web.py

I'm sorry if this is a silly question. But I've searched the web for a really long time. I've googled keywords like "website admin login", "website only admin can login", etc. And I still don't know how to do it. Here is my problem:

I'm working on a simple blog system to learn web development. I want it to show the log in area only when I open the index page. When other people input the domain name of my blog site there is no log in area appeared, only the content I'd like to show to the others. How can I make it?

Should I check the IP address of agent? What if I want to update the website in multiple places? Like today I'm at home, I log in to my blog site and write a post. Then the other day I'm in a coffee shop and want to write a post too...

I don't know if the framework I use matters. But in case that matters... I use web.py..Thanks.

Comment: Just put the login form on a separate page that you aren't linking to, such as http://my.blog.somewhere.com/admin/.

Comment: thank you, @mzedeler. what do you mean by "you aren't linking to"? Could you provide more detail? Like a page hosted by github so that the page is not a part of my blog site? And don't tell anybody the url of the log in page?

Comment: It just doesn't need to be publicly facing, e.g. if I don't know it exists and I am on your website, no amount of clicking would ever navigate to it. (And obscurity it not security, so make sure logging in as admin requires a strong password.)

Comment: Oh, I get it. I never thought about that...That's a good approach. Is this the method that most of blog site using? Are there any other methods?

Comment: And why don't you guys answer the question so that I can choose an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put the login form on a separate page that you aren't linking to, such as my.blog.somewhere.com/admin.

Answer (score 0):

you could also set up a allow, deny command in your .htaccess file and put deny all , allow from ipaddress of the site owners and mods